# How to fix end effector direction to approach object with MoveIt

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My question is that how to fix end effector orientation to approach object(move forward) with MoveIt?

I already let my robot to move to a given goal position(x, y, z).
If I would like to let robot grasp the object, move and approach it slowly is necessary.
So I want to move the robot 15cm forward by fixed direction of end effector.

As shown in the picture:
[image: approach]

Does MoveIt or others have any function can achieve this?
If you can provide me example code with python will be better.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324255/how-to-fix-end-effector-direction-to-approach-object-with-moveit/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [constraint messages](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/Constraints.html) to approach, for example as explained in [q174095](https://answers.ros.org/question/174095/end-effector-pose-constrained-planning/)

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0